# Naming a list of vectors by the vectors names

Tags: r

I have 3 different vectors, and i would like to combine then into a list of vectors.  But i would like to maintain the names of the vectors in the lists names.  Below is the way i've been doing it.

```
A<-seq(from=1, to=10, by=1)
B<-rep(11,10)
C<-seq(from=50, to=100, by=10)

ABC<-list(A,B,C)
```

This is the part i would like streamlined

```
names(ABC)<-c("A", "B", "C")
```

Thank you.

Comment: ẁhat about `list(A=A,B=B,C=C)` ?

Comment: HAHA,  thanks.. little embaressed now.

Comment: Also `mget(c("A","B","C"))`

Comment: If you're doing this frequently, I suppose you could define a utility function for it, like: ```named_list <- function(...) `names<-`(list(...), as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1]))```

Then it's just `named_list(A, B, C)`

Comment: Probably not worth it unless you have something more like: `list(A=A,B=B,C=C,D=D,E=E,F=F,G=G,H=H,...,Z=Z)` :)

Comment: If you happen to have tibble/tidyverse loaded anyway, `tibble::lst(A, B, C)` will automatically set names.

Comment: Inspired by the output of `dput`: `ABC <- structure(list(A, B, C), names = c("A", "B", "C"))`

Comment: @TimGoodman This is more of what i am looking for.  Still a bit confused on when to use substitute vs. quote.

Comment: @MadmanLee A key difference it that if the input to `substitute` contains formal parameters for the function you're in, it will replace them with the actual (unevaluated) arguments from outside the function.  So in my comment above, `substitute(list(...))` returned the call `list(A, B, C)`, whereas `quote(list(...))` would have returned the call `list(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, using @TimGoodman 's suggestion i created a function that does this for me. Wishing list had this as an optional function.

```
named.list<-function(...){
    bob<-list(...)
    names(bob)<-as.character(substitute((...)))[-1]
    return(bob)
}
```

Thank you!